# Django IndexError: Pop from empty list

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have been building a website for a local scout group. For some reason this error in Django continues to persist and I cannot understand where it comes from and how to fix it.

[image: Traceback of Error]

**The error according to the traceback is in my index.html page:**

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <meta name="keywords" content="3rd, Ringwood, scouts, cubs, beavers, hall hire, hire, hall, hut, third">
    <meta name="description" content="3rd Ringwood Scout Group - Beavers, Cubs and Scouts. The hut is also a perfect place to hire for other activities.">
    <!-- <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//"> -->
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/images/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <title>3rd Ringwood Scouts</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/holder.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/ink-all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

---

**As asked for the full traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('flat',
 'redactor',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'events',
 'information')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/Max/Documents/scouts_backend/templates/index.html, error at line 11
   pop from empty list   1 : {% load staticfiles %}
   2 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   3 : <html>
   4 :     <head>
   5 :         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
   6 :         <meta charset="utf-8" />
   7 :         <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
   8 :         <meta name="keywords" content="3rd, Ringwood, scouts, cubs, beavers, hall hire, hire, hall, hut, third">
   9 :         <meta name="description" content="3rd Ringwood Scout Group - Beavers, Cubs and Scouts. The hut is also a perfect place to hire for other activities.">
   10 :         <!-- <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//"> -->
   11 :         <link rel="icon" href="/static/images/favicon.png" typ e="image/png" />
    12 :         <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" charset="utf-8"> -->
   13 :         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
   14 :         <title>3rd Ringwood Scouts</title>
   15 :         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/holder.js"></script>
   16 :         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/ink-all.js"></script>
   17 :         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   18 :     </head>
   19 :     <body>
   20 :         {% include "navbar.html" %}
   21 :         <!-- Begin Content -->


Traceback:

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  109.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  86.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  210.                 return template.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  210.                 return self._render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  315.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  439.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  344.             self._populate()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _populate
  209.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  242.             self._populate()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _populate
  228.                 bits = normalize(p_pattern)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/regex_helper.py" in normalize
  110.                 start = non_capturing_groups.pop()

Exception Type: IndexError at /
Exception Value: pop from empty list
```

---

### Update

I have isolated the issue in the template, here is a section of the index.html file where the error lies:

```
<body>
    {% include "navbar.html" %}
    <!-- Begin Content -->
    <div class="content-container">
        <div id="home" class="content-drawer">
            {% include "header.html" %} <!-- This line causes the error -->
            <section class="beavers">
```

---

**Header.html**

```
<section class="welcome">
    <div class="ink-grid">
        <div class="column-group push-middle">
            <div class="xlarge-70 large-70 all-80 align-center push-center">
                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=20&txt=Logo&w=75&h=75" />
                <h1>------</h1>
                <p>Group Scout Leader: <a href="/contact"><strong>-----</strong> -----</a></p>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <p><b><a href="">{{ user.username }}</a> | <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></b></p>
                {% else %}
                    <p><b><a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a></b></p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

**urls.py**

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
        url(r'^groups/', include('events.urls')),
        url(r'^', include('information.urls')),
        url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
        url(r'^booking/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='static_pages/booking.html'), name='booking'),
        url(r'^links/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='static_pages/links.html'), name='links'),
        url(r'^waiting-list/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='static_pages/waiting-list.html'), name='waiting list')
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

events/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView, TemplateView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='index'), name='group_redirect'),
    url(r'^events/$', views.event_list, name='event_list'),
    url(r'^leaders/$', views.leader_list, name='leader_list'),
    url(r'^event/(?P<event_id>[0-9])/$', views.event, name='specific_event'),
    url(r'^leader/(?P<leader_id>[0-9)])/$', views.leader, name='specific_leader'),
    url(r'^(?P<group_name>[\w-]+)/$', views.group, name='group_home'),
]
```

---

**information/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^contact/success/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact/success.html'), name='contact_success'),
]
```

Comment: That line in the template doesn't contain any django template tags, so it's strange that it would cause an error? Are you using `runserver` ? If you are using a production wsgi server, the code in the error messages could be out of sync with the running python byte code. In any case, please add the full traceback to the question, since the actual IndexError happens in some python code.

Comment: You would get this error if you try `[].pop()`. But this happens in the function `django.utils.regex_helper.normalize`, which kinda smells like this could be a bug in django itself. Which version of django are you using?

Comment: As with @HåkenLid said, there should not be an error there. Something is most likely out of sync between the builds and the actual code. Provide the entire traceback and consider rebuilding your project.

Comment: @HåkenLid I have now added the full traceback, I am using python 2.7, Django version  1.10.5 and yes, I was using runserver

Comment: Strange. With runserver the bytecode should be in sync with the source code. To confirm that the code is in sync, you can delete all `.pyc` files and force them to be rebuilt.`find -name "*.pyc" -delete`. Then reload the page, and see if anything has changed.

Comment: It might be some strange edge case bug in django's template engine. What happens if you just remove line 11 from your template ( and possibly a few lines before and after it )?

Comment: I would guess that the trackback just isn't accurate in regards to what line the error is on. Is there somewhere in that template where you're using a `{% url %}` tag?

Comment: @HåkenLid @csinchok I have deleted all bytecode this does nothing the error still occurs. Removing the line and lines after displays the first 10 lines of the index page with no highlighting in red for the error. As for `{% url %}` there are no instances of this in the index.html page.

Comment: What does your `urls.py` look like? The function where this error is triggered is used for building urls from urlpatterns when you call `{% url 'login' %}`. It looks like it loops through all the urls you have defined. So it might be that you have a pathologically malformed url pattern. Maybe something with unbalanced parens, such as this: `url(r'^foo?)/', foo)`.

Comment: @HåkenLid I have added the urls.

Comment: I would debug this using the Werkzeug dev server and the package `django-extension`. It lets you open a debug shell and inspect local variables in the callstack. Makes it easy to find out what is the value of `p_pattern` that is passed to the function `normalize()` and causes this exception.

Comment: Try to remove the `)` just after the `9` in this pattern.   `url(r'^leader/(?P<leader_id>[0-9)])/$', views.leader, name='specific_leader'),`

Comment: @HåkenLid It worked! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I'll add that as an answer, then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you hit an edge case bug in django itself.

To solve it, change this line in urls.py

```
# pathological pattern:
url(r'^leader/(?P<leader_id>[0-9)])/$', views.leader, name='specific_leader')
# unexpected item in url area!  ^ 

# fixed pattern:
url(r'^leader/(?P<leader_id>[0-9])/$', views.leader, name='specific_leader')
```

Why did this trigger a bug? Django tries to reverse the template tag `{% url 'login' %}` into the actual login url. It loops over all url patterns and does some kind of reverse regular expression. 
But since `()` have special meaning in regular expression, they have to be handled correctly. In this case you have a technically *valid* (though clearly incorrect) regular expression, with a `)` in an unexpected place: inside a `[]` group.

Seems like a obscure bug, and clearly it's not covered by django's test suite.

Good thing the [django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/utils/regex_helper.py#L104) is well commented, so you can follow their logic (even when it's not quite correct).

```
# django/utils/regex_helper.py:111

elif ch == ')':
    # This can only be the end of a non-capturing group, since all
    # other unescaped parentheses are handled by the grouping
    # section later (and the full group is handled there).
    #
    # We regroup everything inside the capturing group so that it
    # can be quantified, if necessary.
    start = non_capturing_groups.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this exact issue, but I need the closing `)` in the `[]` group (like so `[^)]`).
Escaping it did help (`[^\)]`), although it is not what you expect to have to do in a regular expression.